# CNET on Mac - page not found

Tags: safari, firefox, web-browsing, websites

I've been having this problem for some time now - first I thought it was some temporary thing with CNET servers, but it doesn't seem so.

I can see the index pages of CNET sites (download.cnet.com, news.cnet.com), but when I delve deeper by clicking some application link on download.cnet.com or get direct link to some news from Twitter, I get error 'page not found' as seen on the image:

[image]

It seems that all links that point to CNET URLs having **.html** in them yield errors constantly. Other pages (e.g *Mac software* etc) are mostly OK (at least for the first click, but repeatedly refreshing gets me few random errors too)

This happens with all my browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera), whereas it **does not** happen with IE 8 running on Win 7 inside a VirtualBox on the *same* Mac, so it is not related to my network, but with my Mac borwsers somehow or Mac OS X.

BTW, all other websites are totally OK and this is only related to *.cnet.com sites. I have extensions and add-ons in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but Opera is vanilla as I only use it for testing purposes, so could not be caused by some extension.

Specs:

- Mac OS X 10.6.7
- MacBook Pro 6,2
- Safari 5.0.5
- Chrome 11.0
- Firefox 4.0.1
- Opera 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution: **changing first preferred language** in browser.

It might fix the problem if you choose **English** as you **first preferred language** in browser settings. When requesting a page, browsers sends list of preferred languages for content. (For example, based on these settings Google redirects you to your local Google site.)

Changing preferred language:

- Firefox 5: *Tools->Options->Content->Languages*.
- Chrome: *wrench-icon->Options->Under the Hood->Web Content->Languages and spell-checker settings*  ([instructions](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416&from=95415&rd=1))

---

It might be working on your virtual machine if default Windows (in VM) language was set to English. Then browsers would also choose English as your default content language.

---

When my default language was set to English or German I had no problems navigating *cnet* sites. After setting my first preferred language to Lithuanian I was getting same errors as you.

It appears that this is internal *cnet* bug.

Tested on Windows XP Firefox 5, Chrome.

Comment: Testing with Crome it worked. Thank you. I don't visit CNET that often, but now at least I know how to access it when I really need some article. Thanks.